# Return Promise or undefined from function using Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a method which is supposed to return `Promise<*>` or nothing.

```
  myFunc = (id : number) : Promise<*> => {

    if (condition) {
      return Promise
      },
      () => {
        do something
    }
  }
```

Flow throws an error that

```
Promise. This type is incompatible with an implicitly-returned undefined.
```

I have tried

```
Promise<*>?

?Promise<*>

Promise<*> | undefined
and
mixed
```

but nothing works. I can get success while returning `any` type. But according to docs it is not recommended.

Comment: can you show what exactly [you've tried](https://flow.org/try/)? `?Promise<*>` or `Promise<*> | void` should work, why it doesn't?

Comment: It gives me error `?Promise<*> => {
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. This type is incompatible with` and `null. This type is incompatible with` and ``, trying `Promise<*> | void` now

Comment: both [cases works well](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1AWwJ4BiArmsqALygAUAlgCagBcoaxuARgKYBOAlCwD8ABR6xctDFwA8AKgB8lRQG9EodbUg0GfUKvUHQPLlmI80oUeMlcAdMYyxoANy7U+a9QF9EPxCnRsPCJSZAAmSm1GFjZOXgFLMQkpOUUAH1A1Z1gGJT1PUE0o3X1DIxMzCytkuwcnV3cCny8gA) perhaps you've missed something else, share full functions. Which version of flow do you use?

Comment: mb it's kind of offtop, but what if you return `Promise.reject()`, `Promise.resolve()` or even promise that will never be resolved `new Promise(() => {})` depending on use case?

Comment: @skyboyer in cases you described `Promise<*>` is returned

Comment: @Alex this issues is coming after updating yarn and node to latest versions, previously it was working fine with `Promise<*>`

Comment: @TasawerNawaz which `node`, `yarn` & `flow` versions do you use now? Also, can you show full codebase of `myFunc`?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is there is no default return statement after if block that's why it's giving error

You can do something like this

```
{
 if(condition){
 return Promise(...)
 }
 return null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To wait for any type you have to put any

```
Promise<any>
```